# How to setup timeout reading USB port in C++ (VS2010)?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, usb, thermal-printer

I am opening and reading a port from a USB device (thermal printer):

```
HANDLE hUsb = CreateFile(symbolicName,
      GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 
      0, 
      NULL, 
      OPEN_EXISTING, 
      0, 
      NULL);

ReadFile(hUsb, buffer, bytes, &read, NULL);
```

I need to setup timeout to read, but it's an USB port, not a COM port, so I can't use the function SetCommTimeouts.

Is there any function that I can use and has the same effect of SetCommTimeouts?

If there's a simply way, I prefer to not use thread.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 with Windows 10.

Grateful.

Comment: I don't know much about windows, but wild guess - can IO Completion Port help?

Comment: you need create asynchronous handle. as result `ReadFile` not block. and you can cancel call at any time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all any Visual Studio here absolute unrelated.

general solution - use asynchronous io, which never block. and you can yourself cancel io operation by some timeout. good way of course set timer (via `CreateTimerQueueTimer`) and cancel io in timer callback. or if io will complete before this - cancel timer. but if want simplest implementation, which do synchronous io in place - possible do next:

```
    inline ULONG BOOL_TO_ERROR(BOOL f)
    {
        return f ? NOERROR : GetLastError();
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------

    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(symbolicName, FILE_GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, 0, OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, 0);

    if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        OVERLAPPED ov = {};
        if (ov.hEvent = CreateEventW(0, 0, 0, 0))
        {
            char buf[16];
            ULONG NumberOfBytesRead = 0;
            ULONG err = BOOL_TO_ERROR(ReadFile(hFile, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, &ov));

            switch (err)
            {
            case ERROR_IO_PENDING:
                if (WaitForSingleObject(ov.hEvent, timeout) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
                {
                    CancelIo(hFile);
                }
            case NOERROR:
                err = BOOL_TO_ERROR(GetOverlappedResult(hFile, &ov, &NumberOfBytesRead, TRUE));
                break;
            }

            CloseHandle(ov.hEvent);
        }
        CloseHandle(hFile);
    }
```